# how to join multiple form inputs into one database column field, with Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I would like to have a drop down where one can select an option and next to it write the value for that option. In my rails app I am using slim for views I have the following form.

```
= simple_form_for @player, :url => url do |f|
  .panel-heading
     span.panel-title Details
   .panel-body
     = f.input :name, as: :string
     = f.input :position, as: :string
   .col-lg-6
    .panel.panel-default
     .panel-heading
       span.panel-title Clubs
     .panel-body
      .col-md-4
        = f.input :previous_club[name], as: :select
      .col-md-4
        = f.input :previous_club[position], as: :string
```

in the player model I have a custom setter method for the `previous_club`, at the moment I get the error `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`.

The exception is thrown at `= f.input :previous_club[position], as: :string` this line

Comment: Which line of code is giving you that error?  Is that line of code shown here in the question, or is it in the custom setter method, or is it somewhere else?

Comment: '= f.input :previous_club[position], as: :string' this line. I can't properly figure out how form elements are processed in slim

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include that information, and any other we might need?  We need the question to stand on its own, without someone needing to read the comments.